# SourceGrid: how to disable a single cell?

Tags: c#, .net, datagrid

I'm using a Sourcegrid.DataGrid with a selection mode set to

```
this.dataGrid1.SelectionMode = SourceGrid.GridSelectionMode.Row;
```

and I need to disable from editing (with double click) a single cell.

I know how to disable an entire Column using

```
this.dataGrid1.Columns[0].DataCell.Editor.EnableEdit = false;
```

But I don't know how to disable a single cell.

Can someone explain how to do, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to Marek for your effort, but your solution is for another .net control.

I have found myself a workaround to solve the problem. I think that there is a bug on the control that avoid to disable a single cell (or I haven't found the right solution to do this).

If I have a cell with a fixed/pre-defined text, I can block editing with the following code

```
private void dataGrid1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SourceGrid.DataGrid dg = (SourceGrid.DataGrid)sender;
    //Get the position of the clicked cell
    int c = dg.MouseCellPosition.Column;
    int r = dg.MouseCellPosition.Row;
    //create a Cell context 
    SourceGrid.CellContext cc = new SourceGrid.CellContext(dg, new SourceGrid.Position(r,c));
    //and retrieve the value to be compared with a pre-defined text
    if (String.Compare(cc.DisplayText, "SOMETEXT") == 0)
        this.dataGrid1.GetCell(r, c).Editor.EnableEdit = false; //Disable the editing 
    else
        this.dataGrid1.GetCell(r, c).Editor.EnableEdit = true;  //Enable the editing
}
```

I hope this can help someone.

Regards,
Alex